# Matrix addition of unequal matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

From what I know, 2 matrices can be added only if they have equal sizes.

Consider the cases-

```
1. a=eye(5)
   b=1
```

a+b is valid as b is treated as a scalar:

```
2. a=eye(5) 
   b=[1,2]
```

a+b -> This is invalid due to unequal sizes.

```
3. a=eye(5)
   b=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

a+b -> Strangely this is valid.

Here, b is treated as a row vector and added to each row of a.

The output is:

```
  ([[ 2.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.],
   [ 1.,  3.,  3.,  4.,  5.],
   [ 1.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  5.],
   [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  5.,  5.],
   [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  6.]])
```

Why is case 3 legal? More specifically what was the reason behind making this legal? I found this in python. Is this a general convention followed everywhere?

edit- eye stands for identity matrix

Comment: What is `eye`? Are you using a third party library or something?

Comment: numpy.eye(N, M=None, k=0, dtype=<type 'float'>)
returns a 2-D array with ones on the diagonal and zeros elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using Numpy, [their docs explains](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.add.html) what can happen when adding objects with different sizes:

> Parameters:
>
> ```
> x1, x2 : array_like
> ```
>
> The arrays to be added. If `x1.shape != x2.shape`, they must be broadcastable to a common shape (which may be the shape of one or the other).

Now, let's check what [the docs says about broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html#general-broadcasting-rules):

> When either of the dimensions compared is one, the other is used. In other words, dimensions with size 1 are stretched or “copied” to match the other.
>
> Here are some more examples:
>
> ```
> A      (2d array):  5 x 4
> B      (1d array):      1
> Result (2d array):  5 x 4
> ```

So, in your case, the list `b` - which as dimensions 5 x 1 - is broadcasted to the dimensions of `a`, 5 x 5.

Comment: `B` is (5,) which is broadcast to (1,5) and then to (5,5), effectively repeating rows.